# java interface problem

Tags: java

Code:-

```
10. interface Foo { int bar(); }
11. public class Sprite {
12.     public int fubar( Foo foo) { return foo.bar(); }
13.     public void testFoo() {
14.         fubar(
15.             new Foo() { public int bar(){ return 1; } }
16.         );
17.     }
18. }
```

-Am not being able to understand from line number 14 to 16.because I have never seen such thing fubar inside one method.Will any body please explain 14-16 no line?

Comment: Line 15 contains a mistake. It should be new Foo(... not newFoo(...

Answer (score 3):

The line is wrong. It should have a space between "new" and "Foo":

```
new Foo() { public int bar(){ return 1; } }
```

This creates an instance of an anonymous type which implements `Foo`. See [Java in a Nutshell: Anonymous Classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) (section 3.12.3 covers the syntax).

Anonymous classes are often used extensively with event listeners. See [Swing Trail: Inner Classes and Anonymous Inner Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses) (but ignore the Inner Classes discussed at the top of that section ;-)

Happy coding.

---

For comment:

Line 14 is the start of the method call for `fubar` (which is defined above as `public int fubar(Foo foo)`). Note that `new ...` is an expression (anonymous type or not) and the *result* of that expression (a new object) is passed as an argument to `fubar`. The formatting is mostly arbitrary -- it could have been all on one line. Consider this code:

```
Foo aNewFoo = new Foo() { ... };
fuubar(aNewFoo);
```

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: I got your explanation but what is fubar at line 14? because its inside one method testFoo.

Comment: @mrig Updated answer for you :)

Answer (score 3):

This is called an [anonymous inner class](http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/javaresources/Java/innerclasses.htm). A new class, with a compiler-generated name, is created at the point you do `new Foo() { ... }`. This new class implements the `Foo` interface. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
interface Foo { int bar(); }
public class Sprite {
    public int fubar( Foo foo) { return foo.bar(); }
    public class MyFoo implements Foo {
        public int bar() { return 1; }
    }
    public void testFoo() {
        fubar(
            new MyFoo()
        );
    }
}
```

(I have assumed that the missing space between `new` and `Foo` in your example is an error.)

Comment: Thanx now i hot the all explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's called an anonymous inner class.  You are creating an implementation of `Foo` on the fly instead of having to write a named class.

[Here is a potentially useful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284396/java-anonymous-or-not-inner-classes-is-it-good-to-use-them) about what they are and when you might want to use them.

Comment: I got your explanation but what is fubar at line 14? because its inside one method testFoo.

Comment: `fubar()` is just a method call.  The `testFoo()` method is calling `fubar()`.