# Why do I need nested class in C++

Tags: c++, subclass

When do I need to use a nested class in C++? What does a nested class provide that cannot be provided by having two classes?

```
class A
{ 
    class B
    {

    };
};
```

and not:

```
class A
{

};

class B
{

};
```

Comment: This is called a "nested class" not a "subclass". Use accepted terminology if you want to be understood.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398122/what-are-the-purposes-of-inner-classes

Comment: Oh come on people if you do not know the real answer you down vote the question and the link you provide does not correlate to the question I am asking here..I am asking if anyone has ever found any use of nested classes in C++ ...What was the need of it ? what is that something special for which they were designed ? If you cannot answer it you just down vote it great ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216748/pros-and-cons-of-using-nested-c-classes-and-enumerations

Comment: @AdamBurry The first is a Java question.

Comment: The reasons for inner/nested classes are the similar in C++, Java, C#, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting a little confused.

In your first example, class `B` is nested within class `A`.  This is a good idea when class `B` is really quite specific to class `A`, and might pollute the namespace.  For example:

```
class Tree
{
    class Node
    {
    };
};
```

Depending on what other 3rd-party libraries you are using, `Node` might well be already defined.  By nesting `Node` in `Tree`, we are explicitly saying which kind of `Node` we're talking about.

In you 2nd example, if there are other `Node` classes in the namespaces, there could be conflicts.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A cat is an animal. We can define `Cat` and `Animal` classes as follow:

```
class Animal {};
class Cat {};
```

But we have defined them without any relationship to each other, So a `Cat` is not an `Animal`. We can define an **IS-A** relationship between them (**Inheritance**):

```
class Animal {};
class Cat : public Animal {};
```

Then we can do this:

```
Animal* animal = new Cat();
```

Now `Cat` is a subclass of `Animal` (**IS-A** relationship). by this way; we can implement dynamic polymorphism which `Cat` acts like `Animal` but has its own style/behavior.

But we could define them as follow (**Nested Class**):

```
class Cat
{
    class Animal {};
};
```

It is useless and wrong, because we are telling the compiler that `Cat` has an `Animal` type inside itself! which means **a cat has another animal inside itself**! by this way, we can access all private members of `Cat` from `Animal` class. It looks like a cat which eats an animal (a mouse) and that animal (which is a mouse) can see all private parts of that cat (such as cat's stomach)!