# Java usage and point of Inner Classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

Im trying to learn java, but I come across obsticle that Im already trying to understand for few days but I just don't get it I searched videos on yt checked on here but can't find right explanation that I will understand.

My question is what is point of inner classes and explanation what each type of inner classed is used for, like anonymous,local inner...

I heard some people saying it's good for encapsulation does that mean it's not that easy to access class, and also there stays namespace if I want to create normal class with same name? Also maybe if I need just single use of class in other class I just create inner then? and I should do normal classes just when I need it more then once? Generally I don't know when I should use it, I get syntax and everything I just don't see it's point, why should I use it instead just normal class.

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) not cover? Or other questions on this site like [What are the purposes of inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398122/what-are-the-purposes-of-inner-classes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question depends a bit on personal opinion and preferences. I, personally, don't use *local inner classes* at all.

It all revolves around how you, the programmer, **like to design your architecture**. There are no direct pro or cons **except accessibility**.

---

I would say the point of *anonymous classes* is to **quickly** provide a **simple implementation** at a single location in your code. If you need to **reuse** the *anonymous class* or start to create a **complex** *anonymous class* I would recommend to create a *regular class* instead.

Something similar can be said to *local inner classes*. They can be useful if you have a big project, for example with multiple contributors, and you need a **small** *auxiliary class* in order to implement your current class. However you should use a *regular class* instead if the *auxiliary class* could **be of use to others** or if you would **need it again** later. But if that is not the case and it is purely an *auxiliary class* for that one class, you can indeed create it as *local inner class*.

---

A common used example for anonymous classes:

```
WindowAdapter adapter = new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowCloses(WindowEvent e) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

No need to create a new regular class if you just want to call a method at window shutdown.

Comment: Maybe do you have any program example of inner class use?

Comment: Nothing that common. Usually I see some small container/wrapper classes there. Just for the purpose to store some values. The Java API for example has the class `Entry` inside `Map`. Or `LinkedList` also has an `Entry` class. It also has some special `Iterator` classes inside. But in that case I would rather create a package for `LinkedList` and store everything as regular class there. But I think they wanted to keep everything compact and clear, thus `java.util` and then directly all classes without subpackages.